# Fetching cross domain XML in Phonegap 3.4 not function the same as working html webpage

Tags: cordova

I am currently building an android app using phonegap that pulls news data from a XML file from a server and display them (using javascript) . The program works well as html webpage but when it is in phonegap 3.4, the the data des not display. I suspect its something to do with whitelist as if the XML file is place in the same folder as the phonegap it works.

Here is my code for config.xml that i have tried:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="io.cordova.hellocordova" version="0.0.1"         xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
<name>NewsPullApp</name>
<description>
    A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
</description>
<author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
    Apache Cordova Team
</author>
<access origin="http://testproject.com/*" subdomains="true" />
<content src="index.html" />
```

and

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="io.cordova.hellocordova" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
<name>NewsPullApp</name>
<description>
    A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
</description>
<author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
    Apache Cordova Team
</author>
<access origin="*"/>
<content src="index.html" />
```

Thanks for looking this through.

Answer (score 0):

Fine, now your application can reach out to http://testproject.com or to any publicly available resource online in the second case.

But, will the server you are trying to reach respond to an unknown origin?
If you didn't tell it to do so, the answer is "no".

To tell it to do so, you must use CORS (Cross Origin Resource Sharing). Here's how to:

Apache (in your .htaccess or httpd.conf file):
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin *

Php (before any output):

Note:
Using the wildcard * is not safe, as it will allow for attackers to call your script from their site and parse the response.

Phonegap will load your index.html as a file, and as such, origin will be *null*. How to safely perform this operation in this scenario beats me. If you find it out, please comment.